# Reshaping a Data Frame in R separating strings

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, grepl

I have this dataframe in R

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyr)


df <- tibble(
  ID = 1,
  `Zebra fish (one)` = 3,
  `Zebra fish (two)` = 4,
  `Dog-caut (zero)` = 9,
  `Dog-caut (hello there)` = 12
)
```

and try to make this one, but as you can see the TYPE column always comes up empty, how do i fix it?

```
# Reshaping the dataframe
long_df <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -ID, 
    names_to = "CATEGORY_TYPE", 
    values_to = "SCORE"
  ) %>%
  separate(CATEGORY_TYPE, into = c("CATEGORY", "TYPE"), sep = " \\(") %>%
  mutate(TYPE = sub("\\)", "", TYPE))
```

The data frame should look like this,

```
ID, CATEGORY, TYPE, SCORE
1, Zebra fish, one, 3
1, Zebra fish, two, 4
1, Dog-caut, zero, 9
1, Dog-caut, hello there, 12
```

The string I wish to separate is in this format

```
ID, 'Zebra fish (one)--Hello; blah'
1, 7
```

And I am hoping to put it in this format:

```
ID, CATEGORY, TYPE1, TYPE2, VALUE
1, Zebra fish, one, hello, 7
```

Comment: Part of the problem is that you are creating your example with `data.frame` which has corrects column names using `make.names`. For example, it replaces spaces with `.`. Try using `tibble` instead, which is from the tidyverse and imported by `dplyr`. This will allow for the spaces and `(`.

Comment: I edited your question to reflect my above comment.

Comment: @bvowe  Could you clarify what the actual format is for your column names?  Is it like `tibble("ID" = 1, "Zebra fish (one)" = 3)`, or is it like `tibble("ID" = 1, "Zebra fish (one)--Hello; blah" = 7)`?

Answer (score 1):

This may be a good example of when to use `tidyr::separate_wider_delim`:

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -ID, 
    names_to = "CATEGORY_TYPE", 
    values_to = "SCORE"
  ) %>%
  separate_wider_delim(CATEGORY_TYPE, delim = "..", names = c("CATEGORY", "TYPE"))

#     ID CATEGORY   TYPE         SCORE
#   <dbl> <chr>      <chr>        <dbl>
# 1     1 Zebra.fish one.             3
# 2     1 Zebra.fish two.             4
# 3     1 Dog.caut   zero.            9
# 4     1 Dog.caut   hello.there.    12
```

And if you want to clean it up with removing periods, add an extra `mutate`:

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -ID, 
    names_to = "CATEGORY_TYPE", 
    values_to = "SCORE"
  ) %>%
  separate_wider_delim(CATEGORY_TYPE, delim = "..", names = c("CATEGORY", "TYPE")) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~trimws(gsub("\\.", " ", .x))))

#   ID    CATEGORY   TYPE        SCORE
#   <chr> <chr>      <chr>       <chr>
# 1 1     Zebra fish one         3    
# 2 1     Zebra fish two         4    
# 3 1     Dog caut   zero        9    
# 4 1     Dog caut   hello there 12
```

In the updated data you provided, you could try:

```
have <- data.frame(ID = 1, x = c("Zebra fish (one)--Hello; blah"), VALUE = 7)

have$x <- gsub("(.*);.*", "\\1", have$x) # remove everything after ";"

have %>%
  separate_wider_delim(x, delim = " (", names = c("CATEGORY", "TYPE1")) %>%
  separate_wider_delim(TYPE1, delim = ")--", names = c("TYPE1", "TYPE2")) 

#      ID CATEGORY   TYPE1 TYPE2 VALUE
#   <dbl> <chr>      <chr> <chr> <dbl>
# 1     1 Zebra fish one   Hello     7
```

Comment: thank you so much, yours is perfect example but the data i actually have has spaces and not ..

Comment: You can try `delim = " "` then - if you edit your question to include the `dput` of your data I'd be happy to update my answer

Comment: i tried that but because some of the CATEGORIES have two words it doesn't work...basically if i have "Zebra fish (loremipsum fheiwofh)" I want CATEGORY= "Zebra fish" and TYPE = "loremipsum fheiwofh"

Comment: i added to the end of the question how i wish to separate the data

Comment: @bvowe - see the update, though I am sure there is a more elegant way using `separate_wider_regex` (I'm just not a regex expert)

Answer (score 1):

The parens are not in your df when you try to pivot. You would need to account for this before trying to pivot or split by the double period

```
long_df <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -ID, 
    names_to = "CATEGORY_TYPE", 
    values_to = "SCORE"
  ) %>%
  separate(CATEGORY_TYPE, into = c("CATEGORY", "TYPE"), sep = "\\.\\.") %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ gsub("\\."," ",.x))) %>%
  mutate(TYPE=gsub(" $","",TYPE)) %>%
  separate(TYPE, into = c("TYPE1", "TYPE2"), sep = " ")
long_df[is.na(long_df)] <- ''
```

Comment: yes i know but i don't know how to add variable with space

Comment: @bvowe would my modification help above?

Answer (score 1):

```
df %>%
   pivot_longer(-ID, names_to = c('Category', 'Type'), 
                names_pattern = "([^(]+) \\(([^)]+)", 
                values_to = 'Score')

# A tibble: 4 × 4
     ID Category   Type        Score
  <dbl> <chr>      <chr>       <dbl>
1     1 Zebra fish one             3
2     1 Zebra fish two             4
3     1 Dog-caut   zero            9
4     1 Dog-caut   hello there    12
```

Comment: This use of `names_pattern` is easily the cleanest solution.  **Note:** You don't actually have to exclude parentheses  in your capture groups: `[^(]+` and `[^)]+`.  A simple `.+` should suffice for this simple case.  However, if further pairs of parentheses existed in the names, then such exclusions would be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Here's a one-liner that leverages the [`names_pattern`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html#arguments) argument to [`pivot_longer()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


# ...
# Code to generate your data.
# ...


df %>% pivot_longer(!ID,
  values_to = "SCORE",
  names_to = c("name", "CATEGORY", "TYPE1", NA, "TYPE2", "suffix"),
  names_pattern = "((.*) \\((.*)\\)(--(.*); (.*))?)"
)
```

## Results

Given a `df` like your sample...

```r
df <- tibble(
  ID = 1,
  `Zebra fish (one)` = 3,
  `Zebra fish (two)` = 4,
  `Dog-caut (zero)` = 9,
  `Dog-caut (hello there)` = 12
)
```

...we get the following output:

> ```
> # A tibble: 4 × 7
>      ID name                   CATEGORY   TYPE1       TYPE2 suffix SCORE
>   <dbl> <chr>                  <chr>      <chr>       <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
> 1     1 Zebra fish (one)       Zebra fish one         ""    ""         3
> 2     1 Zebra fish (two)       Zebra fish two         ""    ""         4
> 3     1 Dog-caut (zero)        Dog-caut   zero        ""    ""         9
> 4     1 Dog-caut (hello there) Dog-caut   hello there ""    ""        12
> ```

But this will also work for a `df`...

```r
df <- tibble(
  ID = 1,
  `Zebra fish (one)--hello; blah` = 3,
  `Zebra fish (two)--hi; foo` = 4,
  `Dog-caut (zero)--yo; bar` = 9,
  `Dog-caut (hello there)--greetings; baz` = 12
)
```

...that looks like your second suggestion...

> The string I wish to separate is in this format
>
> ```r
> ID, 'Zebra fish (one)--Hello; blah'
> 1, 7
> ```

...where it yields the following output:

> ```
> # A tibble: 4 × 7
>      ID name                                   CATEGORY   TYPE1       TYPE2     suffix SCORE
>   <dbl> <chr>                                  <chr>      <chr>       <chr>     <chr>  <dbl>
> 1     1 Zebra fish (one)--hello; blah          Zebra fish one         hello     blah       3
> 2     1 Zebra fish (two)--hi; foo              Zebra fish two         hi        foo        4
> 3     1 Dog-caut (zero)--yo; bar               Dog-caut   zero        yo        bar        9
> 4     1 Dog-caut (hello there)--greetings; baz Dog-caut   hello there greetings baz       12
> ```